# Error saving entity with Objectify

Tags: google-app-engine, objectify

This is the error when I try to persist an Entity:

```
com.googlecode.objectify.SaveException: Error saving com.mycomp.simplify.KeyValueVersion@60991f: You cannot create a Key for an object with a null @Id. Object was com.mycomp.simplify.Key@1bf3d87
    at com.googlecode.objectify.impl.Transmog.save(Transmog.java:102)
    at com.googlecode.objectify.impl.Concret

> Blockquote

eEntityMetadata.save(ConcreteEntityMetadata.java:150)
    at com.googlecode.objectify.impl.engine.WriteEngine.save(WriteEngine.java:68)
    at com.googlecode.objectify.impl.cmd.SaverImpl.entities(SaverImpl.java:56)
    at com.googlecode.objectify.impl.cmd.SaverImpl.entity(SaverImpl.java:33)
    at com.mycomp.simplify.core.ObjectifyGenericDao.put(ObjectifyGenericDao.java:52)
    at com.mycomp.simplify.SimplifyImpl.access$0(SimplifyImpl.java:1)
    at com.mycomp.simplify.SimplifyImpl$1.run(SimplifyImpl.java:43)
    at com.mycomp.simplify.SimplifyImpl$1.run(SimplifyImpl.java:1)
    at com.googlecode.objectify.impl.cmd.ObjectifyImpl.transactOnce(ObjectifyImpl.java:255)
    at com.googlecode.objectify.impl.cmd.ObjectifyImpl.transactNew(ObjectifyImpl.java:232)
    at com.googlecode.objectify.impl.cmd.ObjectifyImpl.transactNew(ObjectifyImpl.java:222)
    at com.googlecode.objectify.impl.cmd.ObjectifyImpl.transact(ObjectifyImpl.java:214)
    at com.googlecode.objectify.util.cmd.ObjectifyWrapper.transact(ObjectifyWrapper.java:165)
    at com.mycomp.simplify.SimplifyImpl.put(SimplifyImpl.java:37)
    at com.mycomp.simplify.ResourceTest.testCreateFetch(ResourceTest.java:36)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:44)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:15)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:41)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:20)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:28)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunAfters.evaluate(RunAfters.java:31)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:76)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:50)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:193)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:52)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:191)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:42)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:184)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:236)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:50)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:467)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:683)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:390)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:197)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: You cannot create a Key for an object with a null @Id. Object was com.mycomp.simplify.Key@1bf3d87
    at com.googlecode.objectify.impl.translate.EntityClassTranslator.getRawKey(EntityClassTranslator.java:160)
    at com.googlecode.objectify.ObjectifyFactory.getRawKey(ObjectifyFactory.java:270)
    at com.googlecode.objectify.impl.translate.EntityReferenceTranslatorFactory$1.saveValue(EntityReferenceTranslatorFactory.java:39)
    at com.googlecode.objectify.impl.translate.EntityReferenceTranslatorFactory$1.saveValue(EntityReferenceTranslatorFactory.java:1)
    at com.googlecode.objectify.impl.translate.ValueTranslator.savePropertyValue(ValueTranslator.java:51)
    at com.googlecode.objectify.impl.translate.PropertyValueNodeTranslator.saveAbstract(PropertyValueNodeTranslator.java:38)
    at com.googlecode.objectify.impl.translate.AbstractTranslator.save(AbstractTranslator.java:38)
    at com.googlecode.objectify.impl.TranslatableProperty.executeSave(TranslatableProperty.java:145)
    at com.googlecode.objectify.impl.translate.ClassTranslator.saveMap(ClassTranslator.java:94)
    at com.googlecode.objectify.impl.translate.MapNodeTranslator.saveAbstract(MapNodeTranslator.java:38)
    at com.googlecode.objectify.impl.translate.AbstractTranslator.save(AbstractTranslator.java:38)
    at com.googlecode.objectify.impl.Transmog.saveToNode(Transmog.java:109)
    at com.googlecode.objectify.impl.Transmog.save(Transmog.java:96)
    ... 39 more
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have an entity reference in your entity class which has no id.  That is, something like this:

```
@Entity
class MyEntity {
    @Id Long id;
    OtherEntity other;   // this thing has a null id
}
```

Objectify can't save a Key for OtherEntity because it can't create the Key.

This is one reason (of several) why this ability to place direct entity references is being removed in the next release of Objectify.  You will want to change your code to this:

```
@Entity
class MyEntity {
    @Id Long id;
    Ref<OtherEntity> other;
    public OtherEntity getOther() { return other.get(); }
    public void setOther(OtherEntity value) { this.other = Ref.create(value); }
}
```

This pattern eliminates confusion because you'll get a clear exception immediately when you try to create an invalid Ref.

Comment: I tried 'Ref.create(value)' but it gives an error, is this what you mean: "Ref.create(value.getKey(), value)' ?

Comment: If this is the correct way to do Ref.create then how can I do getKey(): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12830906/getting-entity-key-with-objectify-4

Comment: Yes, use Ref.create(key, value).  The Ref.create(value) method has not been released yet, but will be soon.

Answer (score 1):

For each entity you want to persist with Objectify, you should have one property of type Long, long or String with the @Id annotation. This is used as the Key of the Entity. For detailed information take a look at [Objectify User's Guide](https://code.google.com/p/objectify-appengine/wiki/Entities)

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

I just had this exact exception and solved it.

You can get that exact stacktrace output if you fail to use the now() method to synchonously auto-generated a Long Id and then attempt to use that Id.

**Bad**

```
ofy().save().entity(myEntity);
Ref.create(myEntity);
```

**Good**

```
ofy().save().entity(myEntity).now();
Ref.create(myEntity);
```

There are multiple reasons why you may have hit that exception. Forgetting to set an @Id annotation isn't one of them.