# Getting Entity Key with Objectify 4

Tags: google-app-engine, objectify

I need to do `getKey()` with this kind of Entity:

```
@Entity
public class Value {
    @Id
    private long id;
    private byte[] value;

    com.googlecode.objectify.Key<Value> getKey() {
        return com.googlecode.objectify.Key.create(Value.class, id); // When executed this line throws NullPointerException
    }

        // Code omitted
}
```

However the pattern I used before with version 3 seems to be not applicable anymore.
The `@Transient` is replaced by `@Ignore` but when I annotate my `getKey()` function with `@Ignore` I get this error:

```
The annotation `@Ignore` is disallowed for this location
```

So I just commented it out. And see if it will work.

Furthermore,

When I run my application the `getKey()` function throws `NullPointerException` as commented above.

So, what is the pattern to get a `@Entity` key?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't create a Key with a null or 0 id.  Neither Objectify nor the datastore will allow it.

If you want to create a Key from an entity, make sure it has a valid id first.

Comment: I'm trying to persist an KeyValueVersion entity with 'child' entities Key, Value and Version...

Comment: Also as I thought, the @Id that is a Long is auto-generated?

Comment: However, the entity 'Value' is a 'child' entity it seems that 'child' entities do not auto-generate Id field, if so, how can I generate unique id for child entities?

Comment: Right, persisting the Entity first before doing getKey()

Comment: Correct, there are no cascading save operations in Objectify.  You need to save child entities explicitly.  You can either save them to set the id, or manually generate the id by calling ObjectifyFactory.allocateId()

Answer (score 0):

Annotation @Ignore is targeted only for the fields of an entity in order to declare that these fileds will not be store in the datastore. Since, getKey() is a method, you shouldn't use @Ignore annotation on that.

For more info about the @Ignore annotation take a look at: 
http://objectify-appengine.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/index.html

Hope this helps!

**Update:**

For the NPE, not really sure what is the problem. You can try replacing your method with this one and see if it works.

```
com.googlecode.objectify.Key<Value> getKey() {
    return new com.googlecode.objectify.Key<Value>(Value.class, id); 
}
```

Comment: An important additional bit of knowledge is that Objectify only persists fields, not bean properties.  This is why @Ignore does not apply to methods.

Comment: @stickfigure OK I understand. However, I am still getting NPE, how can I deal with that?

Comment: @thanos Right, anyway, why is the getKey() method still throwing NPE?

Comment: @thanos The code in your updated answer will have an error: 'The constructor Key<Key>(Class<? extends T>, long) is not visible' I believe this pattern is only for Objectify version 3

Comment: @thanos I have checked if the '@Id Long Id' is null, but its not null and that Key.create is the one that is throwing out NPE... it looks like it can't properly generate a Key, what could be the reason?

Comment: Can you please add the code snippet that you create and store an object of type Value, so as to see if there is anything wrong there?

Comment: It has a static method create: Value.create("Test");

Comment: First you need to create an entity:

`Value v = new Value(); // create value`

`ofy().save().entity(v).now(); // save value`

`Key<Value> key = v.getKey(); // get the key`

If you haven't created and stored the entity first, you cannot get its Key.